# Qt doesn't show a QImage using openni2

Tags: qt, openni, qimage, qlabel

I'm trying to show a `QImage` in a `QLabel`, but it doesn't seem to work. I have something like this:

```
 ui->color->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(colorimg));
 ui->color->show();
```

And the image is set by:

```
colorimg = getColorImage();
```

where:

```
getColorImage(){
    const unsigned char *color_pixel;
    VideoStream *stream = &color;

    int ready_index;
    OpenNI::waitForAnyStream(&stream, 1, &ready_index);

    if(ready_index == 0)
    {
        VideoFrameRef color_frame;
        color.readFrame(&color_frame);

        if(color_frame.isValid())
        {
            color_pixel = (const unsigned char*)color_frame.getData();
        }
    }
    QImage image = QImage(color_pixel, color.getVideoMode().getResolutionX(), color.getVideoMode().getResolutionY(), QImage::Format_RGB888);
    return image;
}
```

My application runs and doesn't generate errors, but the label named `color` shows only the default "text label". Can someone help me?

Comment: Which plugin do you expect handles the loading of the image?

Comment: Have you tried to check that color_pixel has indeed the data?, Try also using the definition with bytesperline in it... Also, check if the data still there after the return... QImage just points to the the data if the data disappears by any reason it won't continue working...  Also, you should put a snippet of the part where this function is being called and where this QImage is loaded, maybe the error is there...

Comment: @api55 Thanks for your advises, but I'm a bit inexperienced. So can you tell me how I can check the color_pixel content? I've tried with a "cout" and I'm sure that it is't empty, but obviously the output is a series of strings that I hope are the right content (but I don't know if their actually are).For the question of bytesperline, I've already tried with `QImage image = QImage(color_pixel, color.getVideoMode().getResolutionX(), color.getVideoMode().getResolutionY(), color_frame.getStrideInBytes, QImage::Format_RGB888);`,but it still didn't work.

Comment: yo can always try to print the first 9 cells, it should give you something between 0-255... but if you check inside the function and outside it should give you the same numbers. MAybe you can try with a static image (like a qimage with all the pixels black) and if it doesn't work maybe it's somewhere else the problem. If it does, then probably it is getting a proble in this function. Have you tried creating a copy of the array instead of just pointing at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved, the problem was not in the use of Openni, it was coused by Qt. Qt can only update the UI when control has returned to the event loop. So you have to call `qApp->processEvents();` in order to forcedly update the UI.